# Better stream performance when transparent hugepages are on

Tags: linux-kernel, benchmark, rhel7, operating-system

On rhel 7, when transparent hugepages are activated, I get a better stream benchmark performance than when transparent hugepages are off.

Do you have any idea of a kernel parameter (or another thing) which could trigger this behavior ?

I was expecting to have same stream performance with or without transparent hugepages (like in rhel 6) (or only a small difference). The performance difference is around 10GB/s.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent hugepages *are* the thing that is causing this performance increase. The kernel in Cent 6 and Cent 7 are different by quite a lot. THP can optimize large contiguous memory patterns, and greatly help the system to avoid hitting the Translation Lookaside Buffer as often.

Memory management in Cent 7 is vastly different than in Cent 6, in the direction of improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you have some links to get more infos about the differences or the new memory management mechanisms ?